# Can I index my database table, and if so, how?

Tags: relational-database

Is it better way to index a table ?

Comment: What are you using - MS SQL, Oracle, MySQL?  Of course you can index your table but why do you want to?  Do you have a performance issue?  What is your table structure like? Are there frequent inserts, updates, deletes? Or is it purely for querying?  Little(!) details like this make it far easier for your question to be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most relational databases are capable of creating and maintaining a index.
Like metioned in the previous answer, unique and primary key fields are often indexed.
The statement for creating custom index would be something like that:
`CREATE INDEX index_name ON table_name( col_name)`
But keep in mind, while a index CAN speed up your selects it CAN slow down your inserts and updates.

Answer (score 0):

Your database engine very likely creates an index for unique fields and primary keys automatically.

But of course you can also create indexes manually. [Read about creating indexes in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-index.html).

To give you better information, please clarify your question and specify which DB engine you use.